# When I upload a image firebase storage getdownloadUrl() put download url In Firestore Collections but not set it in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an Image to Firebase Storage and after successful upload I am trying to insert image downloadURL to Firestore collection at the same time.

**How to do it? Here is the code in which Uploading Image is working fine but firestore is not working.**

```
dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('stack_overflow').doc()

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
    question_id: this.dbRef.id,
    question_title: '',
    question_image: null,
    question_image_url: '',
};
}

dataOnChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState(state)
}

handleImageOnChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
        const question_image = e.target.files[0]

        this.setState(() => ({question_image}))
    }
}
 
onSubmitData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const {
        question_id, question_title, question_image, question_image_url
    } = this.state;

    /*image upload and download*/
    const uploadImage = storage.ref(`/stack_gallery/${cat_image.name}`).put(cat_image);

    uploadImage.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
            console.log("Image Upload Progress")
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        /*() => {
            storage.ref('quote_gallery').child(question_image.name).getDownloadURL().then(question_image_url => {
                console.log(question_image_url);
                this.setState({question_image_url});
            })
        }*/);

    storage.ref('stack_gallery').child(question_image.name).getDownloadURL().then(question_image_url => {
        console.log(question_image_url);
        this.setState({question_image_url});
    })
    this.dbRef.set({
        question_id, question_title, question_image_url
    }).then((docRef) => {
        this.add({
            question_id: '',
            question_title: '',
            question_image_url: this.state.cat_image_url
        })
        
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error Adding Document: ", error)
    })
}
```

**Please check my code where is problem and how to solve this problem .**

Comment: I have my project of uploading image to firebase storage and save getdownload_url to firestore. Shall I post here?

Comment: Yes you can share with us if helps us.

Comment: I answered. I have many experiences in firebase and firestore and storage. I answered according to my experience. If you have issue then let me know, I am always here to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see your code you saved question_image_url to this.state, and I think we dont have to save it to state as we use state to render JSX.
Once you got url in callback then why don't you run saving to firestore in callback?
And you used firestore().collection().doc().set, this works wrong. you should indicate the doc_id to set because set is updating function of current doc_id.
If you want to add new doc then you can use add function from collection that wrapps whole docs.

```
uploadImage.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
            console.log("Image Upload Progress")
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        function() {
          uploadImage.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
          firebase.firestore().collection('stack_overflow').add({
            question_title: question_title,
            question_image: question_image,
            question_image_url: downloadURL
          })
          .then((res) => {
            let id = res.id;   //receive id of doc added
  firebase.firestore().collection('stack_overflow').doc(id).set({question_id:id},{merge:true})
        })
        });
```

Comment: I have followed your method but it is not working . Can you solve the problem by writing the correct code on my code?

Comment: Your new method i implement its works but i faced some problem .
when image successfully upload then firestore collection set only question_id not insert question_title,question_image filed. only show question_id field...

Comment: @SamadTalukder I updated my answer. I added {merge:true} to set function to keep existing fields of selected doc.

Comment: @SamadTalukder did you check?